# Can the fastapi function name GUI display be formatted or customized?

Tags: fastapi

I have a fastapi function like so: `async def abc_my_wonderful_function(...` which displays on the GUI as: `Abc My Wonderful Function`. But what's desired on the GUI display is: `ABC My Wonderful Function`, where ABC is all caps. Possible, and if so how?  Thx.

Comment: Is the GUI you refer here is OpenAPI Docs? A screenshot of what you see now in your GUI with function def will help, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `name` parameter to your view function decorator to provide a specific name:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/', name='Foo')
def bar():
  return 'baz'
```

This will display `Foo` as the name of your API endpoint in the OpenAPI docs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried setting the name = "FOO" and what I get is "Foo". A moral judgement is being made about mixed case only. How can I get all CAPS if that's what's wanted?